# How to add users to the Azure Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have several virtual machines in the azure network. Instead of creating users separately for each machine I would like to create the users at the network level. It will be easier for me to maintain users at the network level.

I am guessing it is not possible to add users to the virtual network because so far I haven't found anything while googling for the question and there is nothing in the Azure Management Portal Virtual Network settings that hints that this feature is available. If this is correct then would you like to suggest a workaround?

Comment: Users are maintained through Active Directory if these are windows based VMs.  Your choices are a specific set of VMs that maintain your own active directory, or using an Azure Active Directory group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add users to a virtual network in Azure. You can only add VMs (IaaS) and Web and Worker Roles (PaaS) to virtual networks.

In the case you mean to authorize users to access Windows VMs, then think about an Active Directory Domain for your VMs and join all your VMs in that domain.

Here is a guide how to do this: [Install a new Active Directory forest on an Azure virtual network](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/)